# Reading list in dynamical systems

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, ds.dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory, textbook-recommendation

So I’ve managed to gather from various sources, a plethora of books in dynamical systems. Now I’m wondering which of them to read, and in what order.

So far these are the books I’ve found/been recommended. I’ll put a (!!) for the books I’ve covered a significant part of, and a (!) for books I’ve sort of skimmed through without going too deeply, or am halfway reading.

- Brin and Stuck, Introduction to Dynamical Systems (!!)
- Katok Hasselblatt, Introduction to the Modern Theory of Dynamical Systems (!!)
- Wiggins, Introduction to Applied Dynamical Systems and Chaos (!)
- Wiggins, Global Bifurcations and Chaos
- Takens and Broer, Dynamical Systems and Chaos
- Palis and De Melo - Geometric theory of dynamical systems (!)
- Hirsch and Snake - Differential Equations, Dynamical Systems & Chaos
- Arrowsmith - An introduction to Dynamical Systems
- Mane - Ergodic Theory & Differentiable Dynamics (!)
- Hale - Methods of Bifurcation Theory
- Verhulst - Nonlinear Differential Equations & Dynamical Systems
- Nayfeh & Balachandran - Applied nonlinear dynamics
- Gora - Laws of Chaos
- Guckenheimer and Holmes - Nonlinear Oscillations, Dynamical Systems, and Bifurcations of Vector Fields

So, there’s sure to be a lot of overlap in the covered material. I would greatly appreciate if anyone could help point out what those are, and which topics are the most central. I’m sure no one has read all of these books, so just chiming in with your experience with any of these would be great. Thanks!

Comment: You did not state your purpose in reading books on dynamics. Generally, mathematics is not learned by reading books. It is learned by solving problems.

Comment: See also https://mathoverflow.net/questions/76133/dynamical-systems-for-undergraduate-students and https://mathoverflow.net/questions/76133/dynamical-systems-for-undergraduate-students

Comment: Then what are the books written for?

Comment: SIAM Review has a nice books reviews sections which includes quite a few reviews of dynamical systems books; e.g., they have a review of Guckenheimer and Holmes's book: https://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/1026128. the Wiggin's book on Global Bifurcation and Chaos: https://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/1031145.  and Nayfeh and Balechandran's book https://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/1038066.  Among other things, these reviews place these books in context.

Comment: Dynamical systems is really quite a broad classification. I’d suggest talking to people in the subject, getting a sense of what they think is interesting in the subject, and if what they think is interesting sounds interesting to you, asking for literature suggestions.

Comment: I have only read
James R. Brown - Ergodic Theory and Topological Dynamics, and 
Katok Hasselblatt - Introduction to the Modern Theory of Dynamical Systems. I tried as a student (2005) to solve every exercise in these books.
I also looked in other books, but there was no gain for me, since there is a lot of repetition. Therefore, I agree with Alexandre Eremenko: Start solving problems. You can find in Katok's book hundreds of exercises. Katok's book is a good start and from there you can go to algebraic dynamics, symplectic dynamics (Hofer) or generic dynamics.